# Modern GUI programming tools

Tags: windows, winforms, user-interface

Does anybody knows how to program modern and fashion GUI's like this example?

[modern GUI](http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5257/5470335055_01b73edc32_b.jpg)

What kind of tools should I need for developing for Windows in Visual Studio?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, perfect, but the question wasn't about your opinion. I cannot tell that to my customers.

Comment: I will agree with @GSerg some years ago, but today is really different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to develop in win-forms I suggest using 3rd party control vendor , such as Telerik or Dev-express.

Telerik's support is very good and their win-forms controls are pretty stable around now , You could download a free trial to try it out.

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx

http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this in .NET, targeting Windows, I would suggest you use [WPF](http://windowsclient.net/getstarted/). Visual Studio 2010 has all the tools built in to build a GUI like that. There are loads of tutorials on how to do this, I found [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2009/05/22/vs2010-tutorial-build-a-wpf-app-with-beta-1.aspx) in 24 seconds.

If you would like it to be fairly platform independent, targeting Linux, OSX, Windows etc you probably would like to use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). Qt has a pretty good editor focused on developing in C++ using cute called [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools) but if you are focused on using Visual Studio there is an [add-in](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in) that might help you.

Edit: There is a similar question here on stackoverflow that might help you: [Creating a nice GUI in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135092/creating-a-nice-gui-in-wpf)

Comment: Thanx Mikael for your answer, but all the tutorials I found about WPF are related to examples very similar to yours, and the results were still a very native look & feel applications. I'm searching for something more fashionist people.

I didn't know about Qt, will look for more info about it.

Comment: WPF is highly customizable though. You could exchange the standard graphics with your own pretty easily. With inspiration from sites like http://www.uiparade.com/ you could create your own images for buttons and simply exchange the ordinary ones. I also added a link to a similar question here on stackoverflow in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I found very interesting your indication about uiparade. This exactly what I was looking for.